# SNMP information in TCL

Tags: tcl, snmp

I would like to know if there is any function or extension that permits to get SNMP information ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Simply google "snmp tcl" for a complete list of libraries, but [Scotty](http://svn.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/scotty/) is probably the most popular and most mature of all of them.

Comment: +1: That's the one I'd recommend too, on the grounds that that's the only one I've heard of people using for SNMP in production.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you also look for commercial options would be the MIB Smithy SDK package to be had from http://www.muonics.com/Products/MIBSmithySDK/